# Rails6.0.0 + Faker +Devise + Seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I made a Login function on Rails using gemfile devise.
Then I tried to make dummy data in seeds.rb with the gemfile faker, but I got the following error message.
Please tell me how to resolution.

Rails 6.0.0
devise 4.7.1
faker 2.7.0

```
#seeds.rb

50.times do
  user=User.new(
    name: Faker::Internet.user_name,
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Internet.password
  )
end
user.save!

users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
20.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.diaries.create!(content: body) }
end
```

```
#error message(terminal)

rails aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
Did you mean?  users
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/db/seeds.rb:21:in `<main>'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block in load_seed'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:676:in `with_inline_jobs'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `load_seed'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:440:in `load_seed'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:328:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/mypc/study/diaryapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

@RomanAlekseiev
@Sravan
Thank you very much

I changed the code and part correction.
But instead I got the following error message.
Please tell me how to resolution.

```
#seeds.rb

50.times do
  user=User.new(
    name: Faker::Internet.user_name,
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Internet.password
  )
  user.save!
end


users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
20.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count:15)
  users.each { |user| user.diaries.create!(content: body) }
end
```

```
#error message(terminal)
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `diaries' for #<User:0x00007f9e6c78b358>
~~~~
```

```
#app>controllers>diaries_controller.rb

class DiariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @diaries = Diary.all
  end

  def new
    @diary = Diary.new
  end

  def create
    @diary = current_user.diaries.build(diary_params)
    if @diary.save
        logger.debug "diary: #{@diary.attributes.inspect}"
        redirect_to diary_url,notice: "save"
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @diary.update!(diary_params)
    redirect_to diary_url,notice: "update"
  end

  def destroy
    @diary.destroy
    redirect_to diaries_url,notice: "delete"
  end

  private

    def diary_params
        params.require(:diary).permit(:name, :description)
    end

    def set_diary
        @diary = current_user.diaries.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

```
#app>models>diary.rb

class Diary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

```
#root
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                     new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
                         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
                    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                        user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
             cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
                new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
                    user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        diaries#index
                              diaries GET    /diaries(.:format)                                                                       diaries#index
                                      POST   /diaries(.:format)                                                                       diaries#create
                            new_diary GET    /diaries/new(.:format)                                                                   diaries#new
                           edit_diary GET    /diaries/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              diaries#edit
                                diary PATCH  /diaries/:id(.:format)                                                                   diaries#update
                                      PUT    /diaries/:id(.:format)                                                                   diaries#update
                                      DELETE /diaries/:id(.:format)                                                                   diaries#destroy
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the code to:

## seeds.rb

```
50.times do
  user=User.new(
    name: Faker::Internet.user_name,
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Internet.password
  )
  user.save!
end


users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
20.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.diaries.create!(content: body) }
end
```

The `user.save!` which you were trying to **save the user** in `every loop` went outside the loop/ it can also be called as a `block`, so have to move that piece of code inside the block.

Comment: Thank you very much.I got the  other errors.I want you to teach me.

Comment: what were those? pls elaborae

Comment: Thank you.Corrected the article.

Comment: because you might not have given the `diaries` assosciation in `User` model you are getting that issue.

Comment: Glad to help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `user` is not accessible out of the block `50.times do end`. Put save user line inside the block and it should be fine